# Can a differential operator have the qualities of a differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, operator-theory

Other than the case of $y(x)=y_{0}e^{x}$, is it true that

$$-e^{x}\int_{x_{0}}^{x} e^{-t}y(t)dt = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{d^n y}{dx^n}+c_{0}$$,

for some arbitrary function $y(x)$ and constant $c_{0}$ and some appropriate bound $x_{0}$ ?

If so, has the differential operation on $y(x)$ on the LHS been expanded into an infinite series of simpler differential operations such as in the case of the Taylor series expansion of a smooth function?

Do differential operators share some of the properties of smooth functions?

For what functions $y(x)$ is this expression false?

Comment: This sort of real analysis isn't my strong suit, but it seems like you would want ${\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge1}}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^{n}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{n}}$ to converge uniformly to get this result. I don't have a sense for which functions would/would not have that property, though.